# Import dmp file to Oracle

Tags: oracle, dmp

my customer has provided a dmp file (10 GO), and i tried the following:
Create a user:
create user USERNAME identified by PASSWORD;
Grant read write access

Import the dump file(using imp and impdp)
impdp or imp system/password@db dumpfile=EXPDAT.DMP FULL=Y logfile=dice.log

and here's the error message:
Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Feb 23 11:46:07 2021
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39059: dump file set is incomplete
ORA-39246: cannot locate master table within provided dump files

Can anyone help on that?

Answer (score 0):

First, imp and impdp are not interchangeable; they  have different file formats and options. You need to know exactly which was used to create the file you have.

Second, assuming the file was created with expdp (aka datapump, the more modern choice) and you *should* be using impdp to load it, the error indicates that there's a problem with the datafile itself.

> ORA-39246 cannot locate master table within provided dump files
>
> Cause: Check the export log file and make sure all of the files that
> were exported are included in the current job.
>
> Action: A Data Pump IMPORT or SQL_FILE operation was being performed
> but not all of the files from the Data Pump export dump file set were
> included. In particular, the dump file containing the export job's
> master table was not provided.

It seems likely that your customer has not provided you with the complete data dump and you should have received additional files. This is possible if either the "parallel" or "filesize" option was used during the export. Confirm with them the number and size of the files you should have.